# c# NEST contains

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm new in world of Elasticsearch and NEST. I struggle with following query:

The Article object is indexed by Elasticsearch

```
public class Article
{ 
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; 
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
public class Category 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

User can search articles by 3 fields

- Author name - free text should match Article.Author
- Keyword - free text should match Article.Body
- Categories - user can pick 0 to n categories

Can someone please help me to write a query which will return all articles 
where Article.Author contains *Bob* and Article.Body has at least one instance of word *book* and either has category 5 or 7

EF Query looks like this :

```
var query = _unitOfWork.ArticleRepository.GetAll();

 if (!Strin.IsEmptyOrNull(model.SearchParameters.Keyword))
 {
    query = query.Where(a => a.Title.Contains(model.SearchParameters.Keyword))
 }
 if (model.SearchParameters.SelectedCategory.Count > 0)
 {
    query = query.Where(b => b.ArticleCategory.Where(t => model.SearchParameters.SelectedCategory.Contains(t.CategoryId)).Any());
 }
 if (!Strin.IsEmptyOrNull(model.SearchParameters.Author))
 {
    query = query.Where(a => a.Author.Contains(model.SearchParameters.Author))
 }
```

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation for NEST, specifically the section on writing queries: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html. You'll also want to take a look at mapping, since you likely want to map `Categories` on `Article` as a `nested` type: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/mapping.html.

Comment: @RussCam but this documentation doesn't teach how to build NEST alternate for `list.Contains` query